# d3js bar chart upside-down and sliding brushes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

If you take a look at this simple bar chart http://codepen.io/ksh/pen/BQEGRK, and when you drag and slide red dashed areas to top or bottom, you'll see reverted brush movement. What should I do, to make it properly? 
The second question I have, how can I make my dashed areas always visible, and possible to drag the same element again. By default they dissapears when bar height is zero, and it's not possible to slide bar to higher scale position.

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 70},
    width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    delim = 4;

var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 21])
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, barData.length])
    .rangeRound([0, width]);

var y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 21])
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var svg = d3.select('#chart')
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append('g')
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

function draw() {
    x.domain([0, barData.length]);

var brush = d3.brushY()
    .extent(function (d, i) {
        return [[x(i)+ delim/2, 0], 
               [x(i) + x(1) - delim/2, height]];})
    .on("brush", brushmove);

var svgbrush = svg.selectAll('.brush').data(barData);

svgbrush.enter()
    .append('g')
        .attr('class', 'brush')
    .merge(svgbrush)
    .append('g')
        .call(brush)
        .call(brush.move, function (d){return [d.value, 0].map(scale);});

svgbrush.exit().remove();

svgbrush
    .append('text')
        .attr('y', function (d){return scale(d.value) + 25;})
        .attr('x', function (d, i){return x(i) + x(0.5);})
        .attr('dx', '-.60em')
        .attr('dy', -5)
        .style('fill', 'white')
        .text(function (d) {return d3.format('.2')(d.value);})

function brushmove() { 

    var d0 = d3.event.selection.map(scale.invert);
    var d = d3.select(this).select('.selection');;
    var d1 =[d0[0], 0];

    if (!d3.event.sourceEvent) return;
    if (!d3.event.selection) return;
    if (d3.event.sourceEvent.type === "brush") return;

    d.datum().value = d0[0];
    d3.select(this).call(d3.event.target.move, d1.map(scale)); 

  svgbrush
      .selectAll('text')
          .attr('y', function (d){return scale(d.value) + 25;})
          .text(function (d) {return d3.format('.2')(d.value);});
}
draw();

function upadateChartData() {
    var newBarsToAdd = document.getElementById('charBarsCount').value;
    var newBarData = function() {
        return { index: _.uniqueId(), value: _.random(1, 20) }
    };

    newBarData = _.times(newBarsToAdd, newBarData);
    barData = _.concat(barData, newBarData)

    draw();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the strange brush behavior because you transformed the svg to turn it upside down:

```
transform: rotate(180deg);
```

Do you really want your chart and labels to be upside down?  Either way, I think it would be easier to remove the transformation, work in untransformed space, and move and the axes and bars where you want them.

You should make sure that selection[0] <= selection[1] so that you don't have exceptions when you call invert.  When the selection is empty [0,0] d3 automatically hides the selection and the handles.  It bases the handle position  off of the selection, so I think you would need to draw it yourself to keep it visible.  Something like this in brushmove:

```
    if (!d3.event.selection) {
      var index = parseInt(d.datum().index) - 1;
      d3.select(this).selectAll('.handle')
        .style("display","inline")
        .attr("x", x(index) )
        .attr("y", scale(0))
        .attr("width", x(index+1) - x(index))
        .attr("height", delim);
      return;
}
```

Alternatively you could prevent the selection from becoming empty.

Comment: I need rotate feature and in this simple example I've added rotation in simplest way. I dont care about labels, the whole chart shall be rotated. 

Thanks to you I found how to check selection values. 
`d3.event.selection` which in v4 is `d3.brushSelection(node).`

I'm comparing both values and if they are same, original `.handle` element receives `display: none` and all other attributes which define position, size are removed. I want to prevent it.

Comment: `let eventSelection = d3.brushSelection(this);
if ((Math.round(eventSelection[0] * 10) / 10) !== (Math.round(eventSelection[1] * 10) / 10)) { d3.select(this).selectAll('.handle') 
.style('display', 'inline')
.attr('x', '...')
}`

All attributes I'm defining are not applied, only style with its display is working.

My goal it to have bahaviour as [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6498000), but unfortunatelly it's written using d3 v3 and I want it in d3 v4